# Writing File to iCloud - Never See the Directory

Tags: file, swiftui, icloud

There are actually two issues. In one app I can write and read files to iCloud but I can't see them in the Files app. In a different app, the one shown here, I can't get it to see the default directory and thus I can't create new directories or files so I don't know if I could see them or not. I've looked at the other similar posts and tried all the suggestions to no avail so I'm missing something.
[image: Info]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var dir = "Sample"
    @State var filename = "MyText"
    @State var status = "Pending"
    
    let text =  "Mary had a little lamb."
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 30)
        {
            TextField("Directory", text: $dir)
            TextField("Filename", text: $filename)
            Button("Write")
            {
                if doSaveToCloud(folder: "Test Folder", subFolder: dir, title: filename, text: text)
                {
                    status = "Success"
                } else
                {
                    status = "Failed"
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            Text(status)
        }.padding()
    }
}

func doSaveToCloud(folder: String, subFolder: String?, title: String, text: String) -> Bool
{
    var containerUrl: URL?
    {
        if let f = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
        {
            let ff = f.appendingPathComponent("Documents", isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(folder, isDirectory: true)
            if subFolder != nil
            {
                return ff.appendingPathComponent(subFolder!, isDirectory: true)
            }
            return ff
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    // check for container existence
    if let url = containerUrl
    {
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: nil)
        {
            do
            {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: url, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        do
        {
            let documentUrl = url
                .appendingPathComponent("\(title)")
                .appendingPathExtension("txt")
            try text.write(to: documentUrl, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            return true
        } catch
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Okay, I forgot to add the iCloud Document capability so now I can see the default directory but I had to modify the plist file to include the iCloud Container Identifier and the Ubiquity Container Identifier which I don't recall needing before or seeing mentioned. Still can't see the file or directory created in Files.

Comment: I discovered that the app needs a new item, "SupportsDocumentBrowser", set to YES in the info tab (or info.plist), then I discovered that also needs "Supports opening documents in place", then I discovered it also needs "Application supports iTunes file sharing", yet after all that, it still doesn't work.